# I'm using the less than comparator in an if statement; however, even when it shouldn't, it evaluates to false

Tags: javascript, aptana

So, I'm doing a program that involves finding the greatest common divisor of two numbers. I have an if statement which is used as a base case; but the base case will always trigger, even when it's not supposed to.

The code looks like this:

```
    function gcd(m, n)
{
    if(m < 1 || n < 1) 
    {
        return 55;
    }

    return gcd(n, m % n);
}
```

I put 55 in there as some random value, but even when I boot up Chrome or Firefox's console and type in gcd(20, 5) it returns 55. Both of those numbers are clearly not less than one. I'm new to JavaScript, so I may be missing something, but it seems like everything is there. Thanks for any help.

Comment: What happens when `m % n` is zero?

Comment: As i see in your code it is normal to have 55 as result.
Maybe your logic is wrong here.

Answer (score 1):

The function is recursive, when it first runs because m and n are not less than 1 it returns the value of the function again (this appears to go on until it returns 55)

With the numbers you provide in the example after the first run the function is called again but n is passed in as m % n, which in this case is 20 % 5 which equals 0. So now when it runs n is less than 1 so it return 55

Answer (score 1):

You're clearly not understanding recursion and the stop criteria.

The correct algorithm is

```
function gcd(m, n)
{
    if (n == 0){
        return m;
    }

    return gcd(n, m % n);
}
```

Let's break it down:

gcd(20,5) -> gcd(5,0)

When your algorithm calls gcd(5,0), since n is less then 0 it returns 55.

So, actually the base case is not always triggering as you said, it triggers only on second call. The same happens with the correct algorithm but the correct condition brings the correct answer. Since n is 0, it returns m, which is the greatest common divisor of 20 and 5.

As pointed by @recursive in comments this solution already accounts for the case n > m.
When n > m, the first return of gcd(m,n) is gcd(n,m).

Comment: It's also necessary to account for an invocation in which `n` is greater than `m`.

Comment: @Pointy: I don't think it is.  Or in other words, it's already accounted for.

Comment: @BrunoCalza: I think it works just fine without your change.  The original version appears to handle it.

Comment: I think you're @recursive. Nice!